# What should I do if the question I need is already asked, but in a poor way?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I want to ask a question, but it has already been asked. That would make my question duplicated.

Editing the question would need to remove particular details (which are not relevant to the actual question and misled responses) and add some context.

What should be done in this case?

Note that there is no answer. An example: the author asks in the title how to do X but then exposes problem Y, which would require solution X. But Y could also be solved by other means. I want to ask how to do X, providing more details about the X problem, along with a bit of research. I don't want any mention of Y.

Comment: If the question is already asked, and the answer is there, why do you want to ask it again? It doesn't matter if the question is poorly worded if it's a duplicate, it's still a duplicate and the answer may well be well written. If you want to improve the readability of the question, such as fixing grammar, spelling, formatting, removing noise, then submit an edit for it.

Comment: So what's wrong with editing it?

Comment: You only mention the poorly written question. What about the answer(s) if any? Do they exist, are they helpful or confusing? What exactly is your motivation for asking again?

Comment: There is no answer. And the main problem is that as the autor adds some details, it might end up getting an answer that solves the problem but it is not the actual solution to the question.

Comment: If the existing question is unanswered what leads you to think that your version wouldn't suffer the same fate?

Comment: If the question you have found would end up with answers that don't answer your question, then you aren't asking the same question...

Comment: @RobertLongson I think that by removing specific details and adding a bit of research on the question, more people might be inclined to either upvote it or find a solution. I have edited the question.

Comment: FYI in order for a question to be closed as a duplicate, the _canonical_ post must have accepted or upvoted answers

Comment: If you can write a good question, and based on your history you probably can, write the question. No one's going to close it as a duplicate of an unanswered, poorly asked question. Well, no one who's not a jerk.

Comment: unanswered question can't be used as a duplicate target

Comment: Maybe vote to close the original question, if it isn't answerable due to lack of focus.

Answer (score 57):

The correct way of moderating duplicate questions is not to use the *oldest* post as dupe target but the *highest quality* post. So if you believe that you could ask a better question and/or receive better answers than an already asked question, go ahead. In particular, if the other question has not received an answer, it should not be used as a duplicate target.

You might want to add a comment inside/below the question along the lines of "I already saw this question `<link>` but it's not great because `<reasons>`" to show that you have already made some research effort.

Comment: If the question has not received an (upvoted or accepted) answer then it _can_ not be used as a dupe target, unless both questions have the same asker.

Comment: Definitely link the existing question when you ask. There's no better defense against a bad dup flag than "I already thought of this and here's why it's not a dup".

Comment: Just curious – what's your evidence or reasoning for using the "highest quality" post as the "dupe target"? Maybe I just assumed for no good reason, but I've always thought the correct, or maybe 'just obvious', dupe target _is_ the oldest question.

Comment: @KennyEvitt You need domain expertise about the topic and some experience of what makes a good question on SO. Unfortunately a lot of people pick the oldest one so a whole lot of our "canonical" duplicates are actually quite bad posts, in particularly incomplete answers where the complete answer is scattered across several. Or some of it is outdated. Then the whole thing gets ridiculously upvoted over time.

Comment: @Lundin I agree that 'highest quality' is a better metric for picking a 'canonical' question, but this seems like your personal policy instead of something that's been more widely agreed upon. I asked [this followup about this just now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413354/what-metric-should-we-use-to-decide-which-of-some-number-of-duplicate-question).

Answer (score 56):

Asking is cheap. I think you should not hold yourself too much, and just do the obvious. Want to get answers? - ask your question.

If the other question asks the same and is unclear, the right thing is to mark it as a duplicate of yours, the clearer one. However, if the two questions are different, both will serve a purpose. You can know that for sure only when you get answers.

The community will sort it out. The worst you can get - your question gets closed, or sits there indefinitely without answers. The best you can get - your question gets answered, and you don't care about the other question.

Comment: "I think you should not hold yourself too much", I agree with this, but SO is a very strict community when it comes to duplication, poor quality or lack of research effort, that is why OP is being so careful about this. 
Meta is a good place to rid yourself of the insecurities of maybe making a mistake in the SE network. Is this healthy? That is another question altogether.

Comment: "If the other question ...  is unclear" close it as unclear! Do not close it as duplicate. Unclear questions can't be duplicates because it's unclear what they are asking.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Why is it so highly upvoted? Why are we encouraging askers to create dupes and extra work for curators?

Comment: Agreed, this goes against SO's sentiment. This will likely mostly result in post being closed and people thinking SO is toxic.

Comment: I support this answer, but only because a comment on the question states that there is no existing answer yet so we are not talking about the sort of duplication which you can actually close vote just yet. A poor unanswered question should not hold you back from asking a better question which hopefully will get answered. This is assuming there is not a third question in play which IS answered, of course...

Answer (score 2):

I would think the best thing to do would be to **edit** the question.

You claim that the original question includes details but they're NOT relevant to the "actual question" AND that those details "misled responses" (comments?). Those facts seem like *great* reasons to remove those details.

Or, instead of removing those details, include them – but also provide the context needed to explain why they're NOT relevant. That might be *very* helpful to other visitors to the question!

It also seems like you want to 'split' the original question. If that's reasonable, then I think it's fine to go ahead and ask your own "X" question. *Do* link to the original question, but explain why you think it 'really' covers separate "X" and "Y" questions, and be explicit about only wanting an answer to the "X" question in your own new question.